Eisenbud and Harris - Exercise II-12
Exercise II-12 in The Geometry of Schemes says:

Show that the subscheme of $\mathbb{A}_K^2$ given by the ideal $(y - x^2, xy)$ arises as the limit of three points on the conic curve $y = x^2$ and is isomorphic to $K[x] / (x^3)$.

I'm having trouble knowing where to even start for this problem. This is likely due, at least in part, to the fact that Eisenbud and Harris haven't actually defined limits of subschemes. I still think the book gives great intuition though, so I want to figure out (at least roughly) what they were intending. In particular (more details below), I don't understand what it means to take the limit of three points. I've explained more and talked about my attempt below.
Since the notion of limit of a family of subschemes is still not really defined at this point in the book, the only way to figure out what they want seems to be to look at examples. The only example they give is the limit of a single point traveling along a curve toward $0$. In that case, they consider the ideals $$I_t = (x,y) \cap (x - a(t), y - b(t)),$$ where $(a(t), b(t))$ parameterizes the curve. As $t \to 0$, they give an intuitive argument that the limit should be the ideal $(x^2, xy, y^2, a_1 y - b_1 x)$, where $a_1$ and $b_1$ are defined by $$\frac{a(t) y - b(t) x}{t} = a_1 y - b_1 x + t(\dots).$$ The issue is that I don't know how to incorporate more points based on this example. Should I introduce new parameterizations of $y = x^2$, that differ by some "epsilon" (formally introducing a new variable)? I'm honestly just at a loss as to how to use these three points instead of one.

Here is some hand-waving intuition. Calling this scheme $Z$, then $Z$ is the intersection of the parabola $y = x^2$ with $xy=0$, which is the union of the lines $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. If we perturb this second equation and instead take $xy = t$ for some parameter $t$, then the resulting subscheme $Z_t$ has coordinate ring $\frac{K[x,y]}{(y-x^2, xy - t)} \cong \frac{K[x]}{(x^3 - t)} \cong \frac{K[x]}{(x - t^{1/3})} \times \frac{K[x]}{(x - \zeta t^{1/3})} \times \frac{K[x]}{(x - \zeta^2 t^{1/3})}$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive 3rd root of 1.

This is the coordinate ring of three distinct points. Pulling back along this isomorphism, this corresponds to the points $(t^{1/3}, t^{2/3}), (\zeta t^{1/3}, \zeta^2 t^{2/3}),  (\zeta^2 t^{1/3}, \zeta t^{2/3})$ on the curve $y = x^2$. Again, this is just hand-waving; I suspect that there is a more rigorous answer using flat families as introduced in section II.3.4.
